# Programmatically change Magento shipping method in existing order

Tags: magento

I try to set arbitrary shipping method in an order. (In admin area)

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderId);
$order->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod('shipping_method');
$order->save();
```

And when I call

```
Mage::log($order->getShippingAddress()->getShippingMethod());
```

I get `shipping_method`, but the shipping method does not change.

Comment: changing shipping method can cause all kinds of changes to costs and services as well, so I think there is no easy method for this built in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Changing shipping method can cause all kinds of changes to costs and services as well. Also it needs to be checked whether the shipment method is valid for the order. So as far as I know there is no easy method for this built in the system for an existing order.

If you really want to just modify the shipping method, I think you should write a direct query to the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set shipping methods you should put something like this:

```
$order->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');
```

For flatrate shipping methods, you should any shipping methods.